# Разрушительный сбой HRESULT 0x8000FFFF при запуске WinForm-ы (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6

Начал делать новый проект на WinForms, сделал форме иконку и заголовок, кода нет, контролов нет. Запускаю: разрушительный сбой]. Запускаю с отладкой: разрушительный сбой и 0 инфы. Пробовал добавить контрол: также. Что это значит, почему это произошло и как это исправить?

**КАК НИ ГУГЛИЛ, НИЧЕГО ПО МОЕЙ ПРОБЛЕМЕ НЕТ!**

[image: Ошибка]

**-- АПДЕЙТ --**

Спустя 1 ночь и пару перезагрузок + обновление винды, изменилась ситуация. Теперь выпендривается конструктор. Значение не попадает в ожидаемый диапазон. ЧЕГО?

Стек:

```js
в System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.CheckoutFiles(String[] files)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetFileDocData(String fileName, FileAccess access, String createTemplate, Boolean addToHostList, Boolean nestedItem)
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.ResourceFileManager.TryGetResourceDocData(String cultureInfoName, FileAccess access, DocData& resourceDocData)
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.ResourceFileManager.GetResourceDocDataContentReader(String cultureInfoName, Boolean createIfNotExist)
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.ResourceFileManager.GetResourceContent()
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.PerformServerLoad()
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Loader.VsDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.PerformLoad()
```

Код дизайнера + `Program.cs`:

```cs
// Дизайнер
namespace Modulifier
{
    partial class MainMenu
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainMenu));
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MainMenu
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(656, 457);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "MainMenu";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}

// Program.cs
namespace Modulifier
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new MainMenu());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код в форме и в дизайнере формы (.Designer.cs файл), в какой строке кода возникает исключение?

Comment: Нет такой информации. При запуске просто вылетает окно и всё. Ничего другого не написано. Код в форме и дизайнере стартовый, неизменённый (в дизайнере только автоматические изменения, сделанные VS когда я редачил окно) @aepot

Comment: _сделал форме иконку и заголовок_ - это изменения кода дизайнера. Вы будете спорить или будем разбираться? Версию дотнета скажите. Версия студии и тип сборки какие? Пересобирать проект, перезапускать студию пробовали?

Comment: Извините. Как узнать версию дотнета и тип сборки? Студио 2022 комьюнити. Не пробовал

Comment: апдейт: не дает сохранить конструктор, та же ошибка. с пересборкой также

Comment: Когда создавали проект, какую версию выбирали? Откройте свойства проекта или .csproj файл и там посмотрите. Сборка былвает Debug, бывает Release

Comment: дотнет 6.0, сборка debug @aepot

Comment: скорее всего проблема в окружении, что-то не доставили или как то не так поставилось
нужно попробовать удалить студию и аккуратно её переставить: выбрать все нужные вещи

Comment: Переименовывали ли вы имя класса главной формы? Или код наконец-то покажите. Большинство отзывов о проблеме заключаются во всяких обновлениях драйверов, дотнета и перезапуске студии. Установите последние обновления на систему и дрова.

Comment: Так, стоп, это исключение при запуске приложения возникает или при открытии дизайнера формы? код дизайнера покажете или нет?

Comment: @aepot Ошибка при запуске БЫЛА. Уже новая ошибка, смотри в шапке вопроса. Дров нет новых, новое обновление винды установил полчаса назад. Класс переименован.

Comment: С кодом с виду порядок.

Comment: @aepot что дальше?

Comment: @aepot щас запустил, уже все нормально, капец

Comment: @aepot стой. у меня не применяется имя окна. оно у меня сбросилось. сохраняю файлы, нет имени и вместе с самой формой появляется тот самый разрушительный сбой.